# How to draw polygon from table/file using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, shapes, polygon

I can't figure out how to draw a polygon or just a triangle using only 3 rows of coordinates. I have several problems:

1. I can't make stitch corner look sharp (with thinner line it's just less noticeable)
2. I have to duplicate the first line of coordinates to make a complete shape
3. to fix the 1st problem, I have to also duplicate the second line
4. with `\addplot table {};` `\resizebox{10cm}{!}{}` gives an error about invalid file name so I can't resize `tikzpicture` if I want to use `\addplot table {};`

So to make a simple shape like a triangle I have to provide **5 coordinates**, 2 of which I have to manually copy. And to do this for multiple shapes, I have to do all this dirty work for each of them (in each file).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
% \resizebox{10cm}{!}{ % Gives error if uncommented
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[line width=2pt] table {
      1 1
      5 1
      5 5
      1 1 % 1st line
      5 1 % 2nd line
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% }
\end{document}
```

How to plot a perfectly stitched shape (polygon) from table/file without duplicate coordinates? And why resizing command fails?

P.S. In the documentation, I couldn't find anything about creating polygons from the table, only zigzag lines and such. And I use `lualatex`.

Comment: Why do you need `\resizebox`? `\begin{axis}[width=10cm] ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `-- cycle` at the end of the `\addplot` to close the path, then you only need the three vertices, and you get a proper corner.

As far as the scaling, why not use `pgfplots`' features, i.e. the `width` (and/or `height`) key to do that?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=10cm]
    \addplot[line width=2pt] table {
      1 1 
      5 1 
      5 5 
    } -- cycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no need for `header=false` when the first line is numbers.

Comment: Can you show me how to make the "addplot" and "table" settings be applied to every `\addplot table` in current `tikzpicture`/`axis` environment? I don't want same settings copy-pasted for each line.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Of course, you're right, I'd  forgotten that. I see I misread the question a bit. Thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: @Andrew15_5 As hpekristiansen said, you don't need the `header=false` setting, so that doesn't apply I guess.  If you want the same line style for all plots in an axis, I don't know what the best way is. One method is to define a cycle list with just one entry, i.e. add e.g. `cycle list={red, dashed, ultra thick\\}` the the `axis` options. You need the ```\\``` at the end, but modify the options as you see fit.

Comment: I guess I figured it out: `\begin{axis}[table/skip first n=1, color=red]` (another example of settings). But I thought there is something like `[table style={skip first n=1}, plot style={color=red}]`.

Comment: @Andrew15_5 Why the `skip first n`? There is an `every axis plot` style, but that only adds to the default style, doesn't replace it. My cycle list version works, but adding line styles etc. directly to the axis options can also modify the style of the axis lines themselves, not just the plots.

Comment: `skip first n` is just an example setting, and in my file there is actually an `n` number on the first line that I want to ignore/skip (it is used in another place).

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=10cm]
    \addplot[opacity=0] table {
      x y
      1 1
      5 1
      5 5
    };
    \coordinate (A) at (axis cs: 1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (axis cs: 5,1);
    \coordinate (C) at (axis cs: 5,5);
  \end{axis}
  \draw[line width=2pt] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```